# Диалоговые окна открытия/сохранения файлов в Android

Tags: java, android

Есть ли стандартные view с сабжем собственно. Не хочется изобретать велосипед. На хабре нашел решение, но колхоз ведь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению нет. Сам недавно искал решение. Если не писать самому/брать из примеров/не колхоз, можете обратить внимание на:

1. [Android Directory Picker](http://www.bgreco.net/directorypicker/)
2. [Android File Save Dialogue](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/704643/An-Android-File-Save-Dialogue)

Но опять же, это подобные примеры, разве что более отлаженные.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.  Я уже намутил свой колхоз но посмотрю как делают другие с удовольствием